# asp.net mvc Load Database from .mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mdf

I'm building an Web App using MVC, using Entity Framework.
Usually, the entity framework takes data from the database from the MSSQL server installed on machine.

I want to make at login a check, for example, if the connection at database is ok, if not, to take a .mdf file (stored on a cloud server) and use the data from that db.

This will be the 'emergency' database, backup etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: If your database is not accessible from your web application you should deal with the connectivity issue. Storing an mdf file as a backup sounds like you would be dealing with the symptom and not the problem.

Comment: You're also assuming that the instance of SQL Server is running - you can [attach a database](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), but it still has to be run through SQL Server, and I don't think it will load a remote file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DbContext constructor that takes connection string to the database. That's how you can handle to which DB you will connect.